# Stream music files from a Windows PC to iPhone

Tags: iphone, windows, music, streaming

My PC running Windows 10 has a folder with ~20k songs in a variety of formats. I wish to stream these audio files to my iPhone while I am out and about. I also need to be able to conveniently sort and search through all the files on my iPhone.

I'm looking for an iPhone app and Windows 10 DLNA program combo that will enable me to do this as simply as possible. I have no interest in streaming video, or images. I simply want to listen to my music while I am out on the street, without having to copy it all to my iPhones internal storage.

Comment: Also: how do you intend to connect to your PC at home while you are outside your own WiFi network? Do you know how to open firewalls, configure routers etc?

Comment: There's several answers already provided for different versions of Windows.  Have you tried the software in any of those answers?